# numpy array replace value with a conditional loop

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array,

```
myarray= np.array([49, 7, 44, 27, 13, 35, 171])
```

i wanted to replace the values if it is greater than `45`, so i applied the below code

```
myarray=np.where(myarray> 45,myarray - 45, myarray)
```

but this is applied only once in that array, for example, the above array becomes

```
myarray= np.array([4, 7, 44, 27, 13, 35, 126])
```

Expected array

```
myarray= np.array([4, 7, 44, 27, 13, 35, 36])
```

How do i run the `np.where` till the condition is satisfied? basically in the above array i dont want any value to be greater than `45`, is there a pythonic way of doing it. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well the subtraction happens only once, since you did the operation only once, hence 171 - 45 => 126 and the operation has completed. Try using the modulo operator if you wanna do it this way.

```
myarray = np.array([49, 7, 44, 27, 13, 35, 171])

myarray = np.where(myarray> 45, myarray % 45, myarray)

print(myarray)
```

The output matches your prompt.

```
[ 4  7 44 27 13 35 36]
```

Answer (score 1):

Not the most pythonic or even optimal way, but pretty easy to understand. You can try this:

> import numpy as np
> myarray= np.array([49, 7, 44, 27, 13, 35, 171])
>
> for i in range(len(myarray)):
>
> ```
> while(myarray[i]>45):
>     myarray[i]=myarray[i]-45
> ```
>
> print(myarray)